# Windows 10 update won't install printer driver - Error 0x80240017

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-registry, windows-update, print-drivers

Recently I got a driver update for my HP printer delivered through the Windows 10 updater. It seems that the driver was successfully downloaded but cannot be properly installed, every time I try I'll get the following error:

> There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help:
>
> - Hewlett-Packard driver update for HP LaserJet CP 1025 - Error 0x80240017

The printer is actually a network printer. I checked the driver through the device manager and the newest driver is supposedly already installed. So I went ahead and uninstalled the printer (which is now a problem since I cannot simply add the printer again because I have no access to the network currently) to get rid of the update error, but the error still persists. Troubleshooting the updater also has no effect.

Now I wanted to check the registry entries (as was suggested [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/hp-driver-update-for-hp-laserjet-m1530-mfp-series/f06fab12-2ba3-4bfb-92e2-03286b18500e)) for the printer in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print** but the HP printer doesn't show up any more (maybe uninstalling was too early) and therefore I have no idea what registries I could delete without breaking anything.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Maybe even a complete different approach?

EDIT:

- the suggested approach in the comments to install the HP driver suite didn't work for me

Comment: Try this driver package..http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-LaserJet-Pro-CP1025-Color-Printer-series/4052955/model/4052971

Comment: @Moab yeah, I thought about that and I will give it a shot - but somehow I doubt that the update error will disappear when the driver update is not performed by the windows updater itself

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with error 0x80240017 regarding the printer driver

The following steps as explained in this [link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/error-0x80240017/td-p/5252594) worked for me

Step 1: Open CMD with Administrator privilege (Start button > Command Prompt with Admin).

Step 2: Type or Copy paste "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth" and press “Enter” key.

Step 3: After it Type or Copy paste "DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth" and hit Enter key. Exit from the Command Prompt Window.

Comment: The issue reappeared again after installing few updates and restarting the machine. The issue was finally solved by hiding the driver's update by running the tool "wushowhide.diagcab" as explained in this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

Comment: Please include the update in the comment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft **wushowhide.diagcab** ([ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53184.show-or-hide-updates-utility-fixing-automatic-installation-of-a-problematic-update-in-windows-10-version-1903.aspx), [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab)) Troubleshooting Pack Cabinet to hide or show the problematic update.

[image]